# Two line - single item inside a list view - how to?

Tags: java, android

How do i do it? i've searched and looked and still haven't found anything usefull for me.

I currently have 2 arraylist.
first one includes Strings of calculations i got from a previous activity.
second one includes Doubles of results of the above mentioned calculations i got from a  previous acitivty.

I've saved both Arraylists in SQLLITE database.

The best i got so far is:

inside onCreate:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] { "operationName", "operationValue" }, new
                            int[] { R.id.text1,R.id.text2 });
populateList();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

inside a function - populateList(); :

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>>();

private void populateList() {

HashMap<String, Double> temp = new HashMap<String, Double>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    temp.put(operationNames.get(i), operationValues.get(i));
}

list.add(temp);
}
```

EDIT:
The custom_row_view .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#CBC300"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#3200A3"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am i missing here? it keeps crashing when entering this specific listactivity.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace? It might be useful to determine what is the error.

Comment: bit of a newbi here, what is stack trace?

Comment: Has Operation name and operationValues have more that aor atleast 20 values..

Comment: The output of your LogCat when the exception occurs.

Comment: no, they have 3 or 4, i can change it to operationNames.size(), so that's not the problem.

Comment: LogCat isn't showing anything for me, tried running the emulator alone, the phone alone and still nothing (pressed on the correct device in DDMS, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you try to get third element from list of 2 elements! You can set some default values to this list or show only 2 items.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a bit i think, still got alot of digging to do, but thank you very much anyway!!